# config dynamic forms on Backoffice for business and normal usergroup

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, dynamic-forms, dynamicform, backoffice

I want config Tabs under products in backoffice for business and normal user group with dynamic forms. but in help. In Hybris, I can not find anything for limit authority for usergroup.
what I hope or think is the link so:

```
<context type="Product" component="editorAreaDynamicForms" merge-by="module">
    <df:dynamicForms xmlns:df="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/component/dynamicForms" modelProperty="generated">
        <df:section usergroup="businessUserOrAnywaysIdontKown" id="generated" disabledIf="generated == true" modelProperty="*" qualifier="*" triggeredOn="generated"/>
    </df:dynamicForms>
</context>
```

as example **usergroup="businessUserOrAnywaysIdontKown"** in the form is important,  can anyone tell me how to implement it. thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic forms don't provide any attributes to match specific users/groups. You should add dynamic forms conditionally by using `principal` attribute on `context` node.

```
<context type="Product" component="editorAreaDynamicForms" merge-by="module" principal="business,user">
    <df:dynamicForms xmlns:df="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/component/dynamicForms" modelProperty="generated">
        <df:section id="generated" disabledIf="generated == true" modelProperty="*" qualifier="*" triggeredOn="generated"/>
    </df:dynamicForms>
</context>
```

Dynamic forms allows to use SpEL, so you could also try to define more complex expression in the `disabledIf` attribute (but it is not recommended).

Comment: thanks very much, how can i config define more complex expression in the "disableIf", have you maybe some example, 
I did not find anything on the help.hybris